# What is this data type? It's some input data from leetcode

Tags: sql

I'm doing some exercises of Databases from LeetCode. I want to test my codes on my laptop using MySQL. I hope to have a easy way to import data.
Here is the input data from LeetCode:\

```
{"headers":{"insurance":["PID","TIV_2015","TIV_2016","LAT","LON"]},"rows":
{"insurance":[[1,224.17,952.73,32.4,20.2],[2,224.17,900.66,52.4,32.7],
[3,824.61,645.13,72.4,45.2],[4,424.32,323.66,12.4,7.7],
[5,424.32,282.9,12.4,7.7],[6,625.05,243.53,52.5,32.8],
[7,424.32,968.94,72.5,45.3],[8,624.46,714.13,12.5,7.8],
[9,425.49,463.85,32.5,20.3],[10,624.46,776.85,12.4,7.7],
[11,624.46,692.71,72.5,45.3],[12,225.93,933,12.5,7.8],
[13,824.61,786.86,32.6,20.3],[14,824.61,935.34,52.6,32.8]]}}
```

What is the data type?

Comment: ```what is the data type?``` => it's JSON string

Answer (score 0):

This is a [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string. JSON is a common data interchange format.